# Iniciar um novo Fragment quando pesquisar

Tags: java, android

Preciso saber como quando a pessoas dar enter na barra de pesquisa, o aplicativo passar o que foi digitado para outro fragment e inicia-lo.

Atualmente cheguei no seguinte código, mas não esta funcionando.

```
@Override
       public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

           inflater.inflate(R.menu.pesquisa, menu);
           super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
                   //Pega o Componente.  
           SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
                   .getActionView();
           //Define um texto de ajuda:
                   mSearchView.setQueryHint("teste");
                   if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getActivity().getIntent().getAction())) {
                       Intent intent = null;
                    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                     }
           // exemplos de utilização:
                   doMySearch(query);

           return;

       }


       public void doMySearch(String query) {
Search serach = new Search();
Fragment myListFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragment");
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("QUERY",query);
serach.setArguments(bundle);      

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho que seu código ta um tanto quanto confuso mas vou tentar ajudar.

Este método apenas define qual menu será exibido quando o usuario clicar nas opções:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

Este método é chamado quando o usuario clica em um item do menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        action1();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        action2();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Seu fragment deve ter o seguinte método estático para permitir uma instanciação com passagem de parâmetros:

```
public static DetailsFragment newInstance(String parametro) {
    DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", parametro);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

E você vai setá-lo chamando isto na sua activity:

```
 MyFragment frag = MyFragment.newInstance("parametro");
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_do_fragment, frag).commit();
```

Para recuperar esse parametro no fragment vc faz o seguinte:

```
getArguments().getString("key");
```

Espero ter ajudado.